# Wireshark pane couldn't display

Tags: macos, x11, xquartz, wireshark

[image]

I installed Wireshark Version 2.0.0 on OSX 10.11 with XQuartz 2.7.8
But it doesn't display any pane, I don't know what happened...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wireshark 2.0 does not need XQuartz, it is available natively. Based on the elements from the screenshot, you seem to use the native UI. What exactly do you mean by "pane"? The menu bar?

Comment: Your screenshot is exactly what Wireshark *should* show if you double-click on its app icon.  It has no file open, so there are no panes to show.  Are you saying that if you try to open a file, that's all it shows, no packet list, packet data, or hex pane?

Comment: @Lekensteyn I mean when I open the Wireshark, the layout supposed to display three pane(Packet List, Packet Details &Packet Bytes) instead of the native UI...

Comment: @GuyHarris I think when I open this app, it should has different UI... Eh, if I double-click the interface like WIFI:en0 for example, it can captures packet normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean when I open the Wireshark, the layout supposed to display three pane(Packet List, Packet Details &Packet Bytes)

If you double-click on Wireshark, it will not show the three capture file panes, because there's no capture file to show!  That's been the case for several releases now, since *before* the 2.0 release - the 1.12 release does the same thing.  If you double-click on a *capture file*, it should open that file and show you the three capture panes.

> instead of the native UI...

The splash screen (which is what your screenshot shows) and the three-pane list are *both* part of the UI, whether it's in the 1.12 release (which, on OS X, uses X11) or the 2.0 release (which, on OS X, uses Qt directly atop Quartz with no X11 - this is not a "native" vs. X11 issue).

> I think when I open this app, it should has different UI...

That's not what it was written to do - not on OS X, not on Windows, and not on {Linux, Solaris, *BSD, HP-UX, AIX, etc.} with X11 (or Wayland or Mir).  If you open it directly, it shows the splash screen, just like the screen you saw; if you open it by double-clicking on a file, it'll open the file and show you the three panes.

Comment: I know what you mean... http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/fixedbyvonnie-mac-os-x-wireshark-2.jpg This is what I hope to see when I open the app...

Comment: That's the old version of the splash screen.  The new version of the splash screen, in the Qt version of Wireshark, is different (on Windows, on OS X, and on UN\*X+X11/Wayland/Mir).  You don't get what you hope to see unless you run the legacy version, and we're not going to support the legacy version forever, so you'll just have to stick with old (and, eventually, unsupported) versions of Wireshark, or get used to the new splash screen.